# Using Rauch comparison theorem to get a comparison of two metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow, comparison-geometry

Picture below is from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow. I've been stuck by the red line about two months. In fact, I asked it on [ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413735/using-rauch-comparison-theorem-to-get-an-estimation-of-two-metric) two months ago.  To describe the problem more precisely, considering Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, I denote
$$
N^r\gamma =\{(\gamma(t),v): v\in T_{\gamma(t)}M, v\bot_g \gamma'(t), |v|<r\}
$$
where $\gamma$ is a geodesic. Then the map $u$ is
$$
u:N^r\gamma\rightarrow \mathcal N^r\gamma~~~~u(\gamma(t),v) = \exp_{\gamma(t)} v
$$
where $\mathcal N^r\gamma$ is the subset of $M$ consisting of all points within a distance $r$ of $\gamma$.  For proving the  red line, I need to prove that
$$
u^*g (\omega,\omega)\le 4G(\omega,\omega)~~~\forall z\in N^r\gamma, \omega\in T_z(N^r\gamma)
$$
Obviously, $u^*g(\omega,\omega) = g(du_z(\omega), du_z(\omega))$. For calculate $du_z(\omega)$ and explain $G$, I roughly use the following local coordinate of $M$. The point $p\in M$ is presented as
$$
p=(x_1,...,x_n)~~~\text{and}~~~\gamma(t) = (t,0,...,0)~~~\text{and}~~~\gamma'\bot_g \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} (i=2,...,n)
$$
Therefore, the point of $z\in N^r\gamma$ can be presented as
$$
z=(\gamma(t_z), \sum_{i=2}^n z_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} )
$$
So,  $\omega\in T_z(N^r\gamma)$ can be presented as
$$
\omega = \omega_1 \gamma'(t_z) + \sum_{i=2}^n\omega_i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}
$$
In fact, $\text{span}\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\}\cong \text{span}\{\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\}$, we can identy $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}$. The metric $G$ is
$$
G(\omega,\omega)= \sum_{i,j} \omega_i\omega_j \delta_{ij}
$$
Therefore, $(N^r\gamma, G)$ is flat. And the curve of $\omega$ is
$$
\omega(s) =(\gamma(t_z+s\omega_1), \sum_{i=2}^n (z_i+ s\omega_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})
$$
Therefore,
$$
du_z(\omega) = \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} u(\omega(s))
= 
\frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0}\Big[\exp_{\gamma(t_z+ s\omega_1)} \sum_{i=2}^n (z_i+s\omega_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
\Big]
\tag{1}
$$
First, I don't know how to calculate (1). But I think it  doesn't matter, since  the  Rauch comparison do not  involve it.

About Rauch comparison theorem, there are many versions. I am used to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauch_comparison_theorem) or [Reference 4, Riemannian Geometry: a modern introduction (only second edition I found)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413735/using-rauch-comparison-theorem-to-get-an-estimation-of-two-metric). No matter which, the condition is
$$
\tilde K \le K ~~~\text{or}~~~ K\le \delta
$$
But,   $|Rm|\le 1$  imply $K\le 1$, therefore, I think Topping use [Reference 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413735/using-rauch-comparison-theorem-to-get-an-estimation-of-two-metric).  For proving
$$
u^*g (\omega,\omega)\le 4G(\omega,\omega)~~~~~~\forall z\in N^r\gamma, \omega\in T_z(N^r\gamma)
$$
I feel I should build Jacobi field  along $\gamma$ such that
$$
J(z) = \omega
$$
But, obvisouly, $z$  is not in $\gamma(t)$. So I think I should consider
$$
\tilde \omega =\omega_1 \gamma'(t_z) + \sum_{i=2}^n\omega_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\in T_{\gamma(t_z)}M
\tag{2}
$$
which could be treated as  parallel translation of $\omega$. And build a Jacobi along $\gamma$ such that
$$
J(\gamma(t_z)) =\tilde \omega
$$
But I can't understand it and the detailed method of (2).

> [image]
> [image]